# how to use a variable as a part of a field name in mysql trigger declaration

Tags: mysql, trigger, phpmyadmin

Here is what I want to do (a part of my trigger):

```
BEGIN
DECLARE updatecount INT default 0;
declare number int;
declare column varchar(10);
declare i int default 1;
declare j int default 1;
while i<=6 do
    set column = "num"+i; /*will be num1 num2, so on*/
    set number = NEW.@column; /* will represent NEW.num1, num2 so on*/
```

I know that the last 2 lines are not correct. But I wanted you guys to understand what I want to do. Can anyone tell me the correct syntax? thanks.

**EDIT:**

what I want to do with this trigger is when a new row added into the `resultsTBL`, I want to check all the rows in the `guessesTBL` to find how many of them are same.

For example we have 2 rows in `guessesTBL` (always in ascending order):

```
num1 num2 num3 num4 num5 num6
 1    5    10   15   20   26
 4    8    12   16   25   40
```

then we add a new row into the `resultsTBL` (always in ascending order):

```
num1 num2 num3 num4 num5 num6
 1    8    17   20   25   40
```

after that trigger will compare the new added row with all the rows in the `guessesTBL`:

```
for the 1st row the result is: 2
for the 2nd row the result is: 3
```

pseudocode:

```
CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER TRIGGER `myDB`.`resultsTBL_AFTER_INSERT` AFTER INSERT ON `resultsTBL` FOR EACH ROW
for each field in resultsTBL (num1, num2, ... num6)
  number= num1...num6
  for each field in guessesTBL (num1, num2, ... num6)
    if number == guessesTBL.num1,num2,...num6
      counter++
```

Comment: Can you at least post your pseudo code with your expected `TRIGGER` action? This could be possible with *Dynamic SQL*.

Comment: @oNare I did add

Comment: @oNare there is another field in the `guessesTBL` named `howmany`. I want to put the result into it. Sth like that: `UPDATE guessesTBL set howmany = @counter`

Comment: This is impossible because `Dynamic SQL is not allowed in stored function or trigger SQL Statement`, so, you can't make this in a `TRIGGER` but I'll see if I can make it in a `Stored Procedure` inside the `TRIGGER`.

Comment: @oNare dude, I am failed. I just have one question: Can we update tableX after insert a row into tableY? I want that "for each row" statement to work for the tableX not for the tableY?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong. I don't think putting a loop inside a `TRIGGER` is a good idea, but I made you a `Stored Procedure` as example:

**Procedure:**

```
USE `test`;
DROP procedure IF EXISTS `new_procedure`;

DELIMITER $$
USE `test`$$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `new_procedure`()
BEGIN

SET @counter=0;
SET @column='';

WHILE (@counter < 6) DO
    SET @counter=@counter+1;
    set @column = CONCAT("num",@counter); /*will be num1 num2, so on*/
    SELECT CONCAT(" SET @number = NEW.",@column,"; ");

END WHILE;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

**Output Test:**

```
mysql> call test.new_procedure();
+--------------------------------------------+
| CONCAT(" SET @number = NEW.",@column,"; ") |
+--------------------------------------------+
|  SET @number = NEW.num1;                   |
+--------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

+--------------------------------------------+
| CONCAT(" SET @number = NEW.",@column,"; ") |
+--------------------------------------------+
|  SET @number = NEW.num2;                   |
+--------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

+--------------------------------------------+
| CONCAT(" SET @number = NEW.",@column,"; ") |
+--------------------------------------------+
|  SET @number = NEW.num3;                   |
+--------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

+--------------------------------------------+
| CONCAT(" SET @number = NEW.",@column,"; ") |
+--------------------------------------------+
|  SET @number = NEW.num4;                   |
+--------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

+--------------------------------------------+
| CONCAT(" SET @number = NEW.",@column,"; ") |
+--------------------------------------------+
|  SET @number = NEW.num5;                   |
+--------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

+--------------------------------------------+
| CONCAT(" SET @number = NEW.",@column,"; ") |
+--------------------------------------------+
|  SET @number = NEW.num6;                   |
+--------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Comment: Thanks. But actually I didn't understand that. Could you please just correct my own code? Newbie is here :)